# Why does a new checkout show modified files?

Tags: xcode, svn, version-control

I have a project in an SVN repository. I don't get any errors when committing, but when I check out, the new copy shows some files as modified.

Newly-checked-out copy of the project:

[image]

Comment: You need to set your svn to not ignore any .a files.

Comment: See what happens if you checkout with a command-line client. :)